# Javascript nth-of-type and data-attribute (change background images on hover links)

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, background-image, custom-data-attribute

Somehow I can't get the following script to run.

The idea is to swap background images of a div, once the links with its corresponding  data attributes are hovered. To be clear, both the links and the background images are listed separately.

Can someone help me with the solution??

Ps: Codepen example over here: https://codepen.io/eric-schakel/pen/qBXvgoM

```js
!(function (t) {

  class Bo {
    constructor(t) {
      const e = $$$(".capabilities__list a"),
            i = $$(".capabilities__list");
      e.forEach((t) => {
        t.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
          const e = t.getAttribute("data-capability");
          $$(".background__images img:nth-of-type(" + e + ")").classList.add("active");
        }),
          t.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
          const e = t.getAttribute("data-capability"),
                i = $$(".background__images img:nth-of-type(" + e + ")");
          i && i.classList.remove("active");
        }),
          t.addEventListener("click", function () {
          window.capability = this.getAttribute("data-capability");
        }),
          i.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
          $$("#home__capabilities img.fill-background").classList.add("hidden");
        }),
          i.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
          const t = $$("#home__capabilities img.fill-background");
          t && t.classList.remove("hidden");
        });
      });
    }
  }
  
});
```

```css
#home__capabilities {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img.fill-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

img.fill-background.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.capabilities__list {
  font-size: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.capabilities__list a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.background__images {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 1;
}

.background__images img {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(0) scale(1.01);
  transform-origin: left center;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out,transform .4s ease;
}

.background__images img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="home__capabilities">

  <img class="fill-background"  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1428606381429-22224991fb0c">

  <div class="capabilities__list">
    <a href="#" data-capability="1">Link 01</a>
    <a href="#" data-capability="2">Link 02</a>
    <a href="#" data-capability="3">Link 03</a>
    <a href="#" data-capability="4">Link 04</a>
  </div>

  <div class="background__images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830180740-12146c79a1a3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1415226181422-279a51ca056e">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450885413713-176921f199b2">
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: So far so good, dropped the code in here.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Fixed the syntax error, but not sure about the $$ and $$$. Any suggestions for rewriting the script without the symbols?

Comment: Wuuw, breaking my head over this. Too deep in the javascripts to soon, but would be to nice to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Here

I changed a few things  I would love to delegate more, but that would change your code too much.

- Syntax error - script should end on `})` and not `])`
- Instantiation of class was missing
- Variable names and constants were not understandable
- Missing helper functions for querySelector and querySelectorAll

```js
!(function() {
  class Bo {
    constructor() {
      const $$ = selector => document.querySelector(selector),
           $$$ = selector => document.querySelectorAll(selector),
         links = $$$(".capabilities__list a"),
          list = $$(".capabilities__list");

      links.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            const capability = link.getAttribute("data-capability");
            $$(".background__images img:nth-of-type(" + capability + ")").classList.add("active");
          }),
          link.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            const capability = link.getAttribute("data-capability"),
              image = $$(".background__images img:nth-of-type(" + capability + ")");
            image && image.classList.remove("active");
          }),
          link.addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.capability = this.getAttribute("data-capability");
          }),
          list.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            $$("#home__capabilities img.fill-background").classList.add("hidden");
          }),
          list.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
            const image = $$("#home__capabilities img.fill-background");
            image && image.classList.remove("hidden");
          });
      });
    }
  }
  const list = new Bo()
})();
```

```css
#home__capabilities {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

img.fill-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

img.fill-background.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.capabilities__list {
  font-size: 50px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.capabilities__list a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

.background__images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.background__images img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(0) scale(1.01);
  transform-origin: left center;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, transform .4s ease;
}

.background__images img.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="home__capabilities">

  <img class="fill-background" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1428606381429-22224991fb0c">

  <div class="capabilities__list">
    <a href="#" data-capability="1">Link 01</a>
    <a href="#" data-capability="2">Link 02</a>
    <a href="#" data-capability="3">Link 03</a>
    <a href="#" data-capability="4">Link 04</a>
  </div>

  <div class="background__images">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830574887-32e5702033b0">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1427830180740-12146c79a1a3">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1415226181422-279a51ca056e">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450885413713-176921f199b2">
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: This is absolutely awesome :) You rock man! Thanks!

Comment: Groeten uit R'dam btw.

Comment: Groete ùit De Haag

Comment: @Schakelen I created the $$ and $$$ for you and renamed the vars

Comment: Surfing the learning curve here, and glad with the results. Thanks again for your help!